# How to send an array in a route and receive this

Tags: laravel, routes, laravel-routing

I want to send an array to route as parameter and receive this. Here is my code

```
$list = array_filter($list);
return redirect()->route('ucs.mail', serialize($list));
```

And my route is:

```
Route::get('customer/mail/{list}', 'CustomerActionController@send_mail')->name('ucs.mail');
```

When I try to load the route it will send me following error.
[image]

So what is the solution?

Comment: Might need to specify it as an array: `return redirect()->route('ucs.mail', ['list' => serialize($list)]);`

Comment: @TimLewis I tried this but not working. Same error is showing.

Answer (score 0):

I found my solution following here:

Method 1:

https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/how-to-send-an-array-in-a-route-and-receive-this

Method 2: It can be solved in another way like:

use json encode to pass array parameter

```
return redirect()->route('ucs.mail', json_encode($list));
```

and do json decode to use array in controller.